# unable to show doc file using google docs api with iframe

Tags: php, iframe, google-docs-api

I want to show doc file on a browser. I am using Google Docs API with iframe. But it shows me error that google docs refused to connect. I want to get rid of this error kindly help me out..

Here is my code in php, `$file` is a variable where I am getting the file name and I have to concat it with my iframe..

```
   echo '<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://192.168.0.56/orangehrm/admin/images/"'.$file.'&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Based from this blogpost - [Embedding a Google Doc](https://sites.uci.edu/docs/extending-your-blog/embed-google-docs/):

Google provides an iFrame to embed your Google Docs. By default, WordPress will strip out iFrame code for security reasons. The iFrame code will disappear when switching between Visual and Text mode or when Publishing. To prevent this, you will need to change the provided iFrame code.

For example:

Try to change: [image]

to:

[image]

Comment: i have word file. kindly tell me what should i need to change to my iframe to display word file on my browser..

Comment: You can just follow the instructions in that site and change it to Google Word file in `src` .